# Closed subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb Z_\ell)$ whose reduction contains $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb F_\ell)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations, topological-groups

I'm trying to understand the proof of Lemma 1 of Swinnerton-Dyer, [On $\ell$-adic representations and congruences for coefficients of modular forms](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-37802-0_1).

The aim is to show that if $G$ is a closed subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb Z_\ell)$ ($\ell>3$) whose image under reduction mod $\ell$ contains $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb F_\ell)$, then $G$ contains $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z_\ell)$.

Since $G$ is closed, it is enough to show for each $n>0$ that $G_n\supset\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z/\ell^n\mathbb Z)$, where $G_n$ is the image of $G$ in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb Z/\ell^n\mathbb Z)$. This holds by hypothesis for $n=1$.

Let $H_n$ be the kernel of the map
$$\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z/\ell^n\mathbb Z)\to\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z/\ell^{n-1}\mathbb Z).$$

The proof claims that the result will follow by induction if we can prove that for each $n>1$, $H_n\subset G_n.$ I am struggling to understand why this is the case.

We have the following diagram, where the rows are exact.

[image]

The right downard arrow is an isomorphism by induction. The left downward arrow is an isomorphism if we assume that $H_n\subset G_n$. If the top-right map were surjective, then the result would follow by the five-lemma.

But a priori, I don't see why this should be the case, since the image of the intersection of two groups is not necessarily the intersection of the images.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Consider the group $G'=G\cap \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_\ell)$ and try to prove that it is dense in $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_\ell)$ by the same method.

Comment: @UriBader There still seems to be a jump required there. A priori, the image of $G'$ in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb F_\ell)$ is a possibly proper subgroup of $G_1\cap \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb F_\ell)$. So even if you can prove the result with $\mathrm{SL}_2$ more is still needed to prove the result for $\mathrm{GL}_2$. That seems to be Serre's approach (page iv-23 of Abelian l-adic representations and elliptic curves - Lemmas 2,3,5), but I was hoping there was a way of making sense of the above statement.

Comment: Yes, you will have to prove that $G'\to \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_\ell)$ is onto. This follows for example by the fact the latter is perfect (for $\ell\neq 2$) and by the fact that the commutator group of $G$ is contained in $G'$.

Comment: @UriBader Ah that makes sense and greatly simplifies the proof I have of this lemma. But that argument still wouldn't show that the top-right map in the diagram is surjective, since $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z/\ell^{n-1}\mathbb Z)$ is (I think!) not perfect. Is there a way of making sense of Swinnerton-Dyer's argument?

Comment: But ${\rm SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}/\ell^{n-1} \mathbb{Z})$ is perfect (at least if $\ell \geq 5$), because it is generated by elements $x = S$, $y = ST$ where $x$ has order $4$, $y$ has order $6$ and $xy = -T$ has order $\ell^{n-1}$.

Comment: @JeremyRouse In fact, it perfect for every $\ell\neq 2$. You can see this by induction, proving that the kernel of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/\ell^n)\to \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/\ell^{n-1})$ is in the commutator group.

Comment: Isn't this just obvious? You have a subgroup of $G_n$ containing $H_n$ so it's a union of cosets of $H_n$, and by induction it's all of the cosets as it contains an element of each.

Comment: @znt Any chance you can clarify? $G_n\cap\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z/\ell^n)$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z/\ell^n)$ containing $H_n$ and so is a union of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z/\ell^n)$-cosets of $H_n$. How does the induction hypothesis tell you that it contains an element of each coset? Have I misunderstood?

Comment: I see, I'm running into the same issue as you -- the point is that $SL_2$ isn't $GL_2$. You might have to intersect everything with $SL_2$. Is this even right for $\ell=2$? Doesn't $SL_2(Z/2)$ have a faithful 2-dimensional representation and $G$ could be the image?

Comment: @znt I should've said in the question - this does require $\ell>3$. Even if you intersect everything with $\mathrm{SL}_2$ you still run into the same problem trying to deduce the result for $\mathrm{GL}_2$. The fact that $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z/\ell^n)$ is a perfect group does solve the problem, but the five lemma and perfect groups seems a lot to cram into a statement like "the result will follow".